How to insert CSV file from Azure Repo to Azure SQL Database via Release Pipeline?
I am trying to publish a csv file which is currently stored in an Azure Repo and would like to insert the csv content into an Azure SQL database by a release pipeline. Technically, will it be feasible? As I keep hitting the "Operating system error code 997(Overlapped I/O operation is in progress.)." error.
Sample CSV data:
"True", "123,234325", "abc"

Here is the script that I used:
Bulk Insert TargetTableName
from 'ArtifactAlias\foldername\filename.csv'
with
(
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    FIELDQUOTE = '"'
)


We need more details…

Yes it is technically feasible. What piece of code raises that error? Are you using self hosted or Azure Pipelines?

@Nick.Mc, I am using Azure Pipelines. According to the deployment log, it doesn't specify which part of code causes this error. Actually, I also tested to insert the csv file from local to the same Azure SQL DB via SSMS. it shows the same error.

@Dai, I have supplemented the script. Thanks.

Are you able to run that script without using pipelines? It seems that you need to run that script on the SQL server rather than on other machines like pipeline agents. See the information here.

@AlvinZhao-MSFT, I did try to run it in SSMS. It throws the same error.

We probably need to figure out other options like bcp tool.

@AlvinZhao-MSFT, I did explore bcp too. However, my csv file contains text qualifier while bcp does not provide this argument. The whole story will get more complicated.

That's indeed more complicated. Can you provide a sample csv contents to explain your requirements? BTW, Azure Pipelines are only a type of automation tool, if you cannot use that tool locally, it will probably fail in pipelines. You may edit your original post with all the requirements to engage the insights from the community experts.

@akaya_1992, I have updated the answer to export the expected contents into a new csv file during the pipeline agent job and use it to run bcp command. Hope it can resolve your query in this post. Thx for the sharing and efforts.

Update
Per your supplement and your possible requirement to protect the , that can be used in each field of your csv contents, I would suggest running the PowerShell script below during agent job to generate a new csv file with no headers, where your current delimiter (,) is changed to be another one (| in my case) that won't conflict with the data in the fields; it also will change the True/False field to be 1/0 for import.
SampleTable
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleTable] (
    [IsTrueFalse] BIT NOT NULL,
    [Number] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Remark] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

sample.csv
IsTrueFalse,Number,Remark
"True", "123,234325", "abc"
"False", "456,567890", "efg"

noheaders.csv
1| 123,234325| abc
0| 456,567890| efg

PowerShell script used in release pipeline
# Define file paths
$inputFile = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\_azuresql\sample.csv"
$outputFile = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\_azuresql\noheaders.csv"

# Read the input file content
$content = Get-Content $inputFile

# Process each line: replace `",` with `|`, remove quotes, and convert "True"/"False" to 1/0
$content | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object {
    # Replace `",` with `|` and then remove all remaining quotes
    $line = $_ -replace '",', '|' -replace '"', ''
   
    # Convert "True"/"False" to 1/0 for the IsTrueFalse column
    $fields = $line -split '\|'
    $fields[0] = if ($fields[0] -eq 'True') { '1' } elseif ($fields[0] -eq 'False') { '0' } else { $fields[0] }
    $fields -join '|'
} | Set-Content $outputFile

echo "Checking the contents of $outputFile..."
Get-Content $outputFile

echo "Checking bcp version..."
bcp -v

echo "Running bcp command..."
bcp SampleTable in "$outputFile" -S $(AzureSQLServer) -d $(AzureSQLDB) -U $(AzureSQLServerAdmin) -P $(AzureSQLServerAdminPWD) -q -c -t "|"  # Pipe delimiter




From the expression FIRSTROW = 2 of your SQL script, I could see your csv file should have the first line of headers. For this you may remove the first line and output the expected contents into a new file during the pipeline agent job. Here is the updated PowerShell script for your reference.
# Define file paths
$inputFile = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\_azuresql\test.csv"
$outputFile = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\_azuresql\noheaders.csv"

# Read the input CSV file, skip the first line (header), and write the result to the output file
Get-Content $inputFile | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content $outputFile

echo "Checking bcp version..."
bcp -v

echo "Running bcp command..."
bcp Users in "$outputFile" -S $(AzureSQLServer) -d $(AzureSQLDB) -U $(AzureSQLServerAdmin) -P $(AzureSQLServerAdminPWD) -q -c -t ","


Based on your description, it appears that you need to run the SQL script on the SQL rather than on the pipeline agent machine, as discussed in this thread.
According to this document on how to Load data from CSV file into a database (bcp) - Azure SQL | Microsoft Learn, we could use the BCP tool to import csv contents into an Azure SQL DB table.
Following that direction, I tested with the sample release pipeline running on the windows-latest Microsoft-hosted agent and managed to import the contents of the csv file.

I created a table Users for test in Azure SQL DB;


Added a test.csv file in my repo with the contents like below;


In a release pipeline, added the repo as artifacts and ran the PowerShell script;
echo "Checking bcp version..."
bcp -v

echo "Running bcp command..."
bcp Users in "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_azuresql/test.csv" -S 
$(AzureSQLServer) -d $(AzureSQLDB) -U $(AzureSQLServerAdmin) -P 
$(AzureSQLServerAdminPWD) -q -c -t ","



As the release was succeeded, we could check the update in the table;





Hi @Alvin Zhao, highly appreciate for your help~ May I know if you also tested with a csv file having text qualifier?

I don't quite understand what you mean by text qualifier. Can you share a sample in your original post? Thx.

no problem. supplemented.

@akaya_1992, Please see my updated answer according to your supplement.

Zhao, I have managed to get the same result by adding a run python script step but still appreciate for your big effort on this.
